# Centos 6.3, haproxy ports not opening

Tags: centos, haproxy

I'm trying to set up a layer 4 load balancer on a linux centos 6.3 server with haproxy,

the script i use is this one below, but the problem is when i start the haproxy service the ports that i want to use do not open.

```
global
log         127.0.0.1 local2 
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon

defaults
mode        tcp
log         global
option      dontlognull
option      redispatch
timeout connect 10000 # default 10 second time out if a backend is not found
timeout client 300000
timeout server 300000
maxconn     60000
retries     3


listen proxy1 mainserverip:13337
mode tcp
balance leastconn
server proxy1_1 proxyserverip(local):1337
```

Comment: Is that 13337 port opened? Check your firewall?

Comment: Had something to do with the iptables configuration, firewall was blocking the connections, i fixed that but thx :)